# Running plugin migrations when other plugin is installed?

Tags: plugin-development, migration

I'm creating a plugin (A) that has optional support for another 3rd party plugin (B). When my plugin A is installed, I create a number of tables. If plugin B is also installed my migrations create further tables specifically for plugin B.

The problem is if someone installs plugin A, then only installs plugin B afterward, my custom tables are never created.

How can I create tables/run migrations only when a plugin (B) is installed?

**EDIT**

I've been able to get this working with the following:

```
Event::on(
  Plugins::class,
  Plugins::EVENT_AFTER_INSTALL_PLUGIN,
  function (Event $event) {
    if ($event->plugin->handle == "pluginB") {
      $migration = new migrations\m201031_120401_add_pluginB_support();
      $migration->safeUp();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have plugin A listen for the `EVENT_AFTER_INSTALL_PLUGIN` event.

It could then check if `$plugin->handle` is for plugin B and if so, run any additional install migrations or logic.

You could do something similar for the `EVENT_AFTER_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN` event to clean things up in the case where one gets uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I've got the event listening and handle check now, but not sure on how to run migrations independently? If I try use the `$plugin->getMigrator()->migrateUp("name_of_migration")` I get an error as that migration has already been run (or at least added to the migration table).

Comment: Ah, I'm able to just run the migration and its `safeUp` method just as a regular class method (see original question update). Is this a sensible approach to running a migration outside of the migrator? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yup, seems reasonable to me.